# looping over twitter feed and return a message once

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am looping over a twitter feed and everything in my code works fine, but I am struggling with one thing. The if statement towards the bottom returns all messages that have a date for today. Then based on that I have a regex pattern I am trying to test for. If its found I state "found it" and if not I state "not found". What I need help with is the not found part. Rather than stating "not found" for each message how can I make it so that it will loop over the messages and if found state "found it" and stop everything, but if not found pass over the message and then once all the looping is done state "not found" only once.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=google');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$twitter = $xml->xpath("//item");

foreach ($twitter as $item) {
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
    $date = new DateTime($item->pubdate);
    $date->setTimeZone($timezone);
    $twitter_date = $date->format("F j Y");
    $todays_date = date("F j Y");

    if ($twitter_date == $todays_date) {
        $text = $item->title;
        $pattern = '/\s\d\s\d/i';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $text, $codes)) {
            if (isset($codes[0])) {
                echo 'found it!';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'not found';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a flag variable `$found` to track whether it was found, and then `break` out of the loop when one is found. Then after your `foreach` loop, check the value of `$found`.

```
$found = false;
foreach ($twitter as $item) {
    // ...
    if ($twitter_date == $todays_date) {
        $text = $item->title;
        $pattern = '/\s\d\s\d/i';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $text, $codes)) {
            if (isset($codes[0])) {
                $found = true;
                echo 'found it!';
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: Move `not found` _outside the loop_. The OP is asking to print not found after the loop completes.